# possibility of having 2 mercurial servers, using the same database

Tags: mercurial, rhodecode

I have a Mercurial server on a simple server (Virtual Machine (VM)), and about 100 users with access. And from time to time, requests have been slow.

And since I can not change the hardware of this server, because the VM server no longer has available resources, and migrating it would do a great job.

**I would like to know it is possible to have 2 mercurial servers, using the same database**, because this would balance the load, and in one server would put a large team, and in the other the other teams. In short, I can not mess with the server you're on today.

**VM:**

```
Windows Server 2003 SP2  
1.5GB Memory  
60GB HD
```

**Settings:**

```
Python 2.7.2  
Mercurial 2.5.4  
RhodeCode 1.6.0rc1
```

---

<sup>***Note:***

Sorry if you're confused, this question was translated via google. If you can edit and rearrange it, I'll be very grateful.</sup>

Comment: Mercurial 2.5.4 is very old. If you're concerned about performance you may want to try updating mercurial on your server. There have been a large number of performance improvements since 2.5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible. If you have shares storage RhodeCode can use the same DB and load-balance load between machines.

Btw, 1.6.0 is very old I'd take a chance at upgrading this.

Comment: I can not create an environment to test if upgrading would have no problem, but thanks for the answer, I'll search on what I said.